# VB.Net Correct code doesn't work?

Tags: vb.net

I do not get any syntax errors in the code below, but when I compile the code I get the Msgbox("cant post status") instead of the output from main.p(x).status(0). The x and 0 can be any number and I always get the cant post status box. What bugs me most is that I have a debug form with a richtextbox that I load all the data from all seven occurrences of the array: p into when the program starts, and it works just fine. I've included that code as well at the very bottom. Before I run the logging sub, I run an initialization sub that puts a default value into every variable. When I don't have the try/catch in the main_loop, I do not get an error, but all execution stops. My computer doesn't freeze, but actions that should take place after that sub do not. Does anyone know why I can't make a call to main.p(x).status(0) inside this sub?

```
    'Main Class'
    Public p(6) as structs.player

    Public Shared Sub main_loop()
        For x As Integer = 0 To (Main.p.Count - 1) Step 1
            If Main.check_act(x) = False Then
                MsgBox("past check act")
                If Main.p(x).pos >= 1 And Main.p(x).pos <= 3 Then
                    MsgBox("past pos; pre death")
                    Try
                        MsgBox(Main.p(x).status(0))
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox("cant post status")
                        End
                    End Try
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    'Structs Class'
    Public Structure player

        Dim name As String
        Dim type As String
        Dim pos As Integer
        Dim wait As Integer

        Dim mhp As Integer
        Dim chp As Integer
        Dim mmp As Integer
        Dim cmp As Integer
        Dim map As Integer
        Dim cap As Integer

        Dim atk As Integer
        Dim def As Integer
        Dim mak As Integer
        Dim mdf As Integer
        Dim spd As Integer
        Dim acc As Integer
        Dim eva As Integer
        Dim crt As Integer

        Dim status() As Integer
        Dim stats() As Integer
        Dim statr() As Integer
        Dim elems() As Integer
        Dim elemr() As Integer

        Dim abl() As Boolean

    End Structure


    'Debug Class'
    Public Shared Sub log(p As player)

        'Stats'
        Debug.log.Text += ">>> " & p.name.ToString & " <<<" & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "Type: " & p.type.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "Pos: " & p.pos.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "Wait: " & p.wait.ToString & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

        Debug.log.Text += "HP: " & p.mhp.ToString & _
            "/" & p.chp.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "MP: " & p.mmp.ToString & _
            "/" & p.cmp.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "AP: " & p.map.ToString & _
            "/" & p.cap.ToString & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

        Debug.log.Text += "ATK: " & p.atk.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "DEF: " & p.def.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "MAK: " & p.mak.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "MDF: " & p.mdf.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "SPD: " & p.spd.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "ACC: " & p.acc.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "EVA: " & p.eva.ToString & Chr(10)
        Debug.log.Text += "CRT: " & p.crt.ToString & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

        'Status And Elements'
        For x As Integer = 0 To (p.status.Count - 1) Step 1
            Debug.log.Text += p.status(x).ToString & Chr(10)
        Next
        Debug.log.Text += Chr(10)
        For x As Integer = 0 To (p.stats.Count - 1) Step 1
            Debug.log.Text += p.stats(x).ToString & Chr(10)
        Next
        Debug.log.Text += Chr(10)
        For x As Integer = 0 To (p.statr.Count - 1) Step 1
            Debug.log.Text += p.statr(x).ToString & Chr(10)
        Next
        Debug.log.Text += Chr(10)
        For x As Integer = 0 To (p.elems.Count - 1) Step 1
            Debug.log.Text += p.elems(x).ToString & Chr(10)
        Next
        Debug.log.Text += Chr(10)
        For x As Integer = 0 To (p.elemr.Count - 1) Step 1
            Debug.log.Text += p.elemr(x).ToString & Chr(10)
        Next
        Debug.log.Text += Chr(10)

        'Abilities'
        For x As Integer = 0 To (p.abl.Count - 1) Step 1
            Debug.log.Text += p.abl(x).ToString & Chr(10)
        Next
        Debug.log.Text += Chr(10)

    End Sub
```

Comment: what happens if you put a breakpoint on the msgbox(can't post)  line and look at the ex?

Comment: @zever  did you ever put anything in `status` to show?

Comment: You have to look at the exception instead of just returning messagebox `"cant post status"` replace it to  `MsgBox("cant post status because " + ex.Message)`

Comment: The problem is most likely the `status` array it's never initialized so the element 0 will not exist.

Comment: I have initialized every variable inside of the structure p for all array instances of p. I can verify this by the output of the debug section. I put the exception in the message box and got this: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. It also mention the sub name, file path and the line it occurred on.

Comment: Why is `main_loop` `Shared`? If it’s `Shared`, `p` should be `Shared`. Also, you can take out the parentheses in all your `For` loops, remove all the `Step 1`s, change `Main.check_act(x) = False` to `Not check_act(x)`, `And` to `AndAlso`, `MsgBox` to `MessageBox.Show`, make `Debug.log` a proper function, use `&=` for concatenation, and take out all your `Try` blocks. If you have a `Try` anywhere, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @minitech Everything you mentioned is preference, and do not appreciate being told my preferences are wrong. If you do not have a solution please do not bother commenting. main_loop is shared because I may need to call it from another class at some point. I have tried sharing p and that does not help. The only reason I shared main_loop instead of just having it public is that other classes cannot properly call it with out it being shared.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly debugged the code an determined that status(0) is the issue.
The following screen image shows the error ...

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that to show up, but I know that can't be right. Before I get to the "error" I output the data to a richtectbox on another form. How is it that I can output the data early on, but cannot reference it later?

Comment: Perhaps you can set a break point on the following line:
"MsgBox(Main.p(x).status(0))" 
... and then examine the contents of p(x).status(0)

Comment: I'm never used breakpoints before so I may be doing it wrong, but I'm not getting any errors or anything except that it's stopping the execution. I'm not able to see what the contents of p(x).status(0) is.

Comment: Consider reviewing the following ...  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: Thanks for the article. When I try to put a conditional breakpoint in, I get a popup that says: The breakpoint cannot be set: Main.p(x).status(0) has changed. Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. I also get the same popup when I set the condition to: Is True. I also cannot get anything to display the picture you posted above to show me what p(x).status(0) is when it tries to execute.